# Python multiple number guessing game

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to create a number guessing game with multiple numbers. The computer generates 4 random numbers between 1 and 9 and then the user has 10 chances to guess the correct numbers. I need the feedback to display as `YYYY` for 4 correct numbers guessed, `YNNY` for first and last number guessed etc. (you get the point). the code below keeps coming back saying `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
from random import randint

guessesTaken = 0
randomNumber = []

for x in range(4):
        tempNumber = randint(1, 9)
        randomNumber.append(tempNumber)

Guess = []
Guess.append(list(input("Guess Number: ")))

print(randomNumber)
print(Guess)

if randomNumber[0] == Guess[0]:
    print("Y")
elif randomNumber[1] == Guess[1]:
    print("Y")
elif randomNumber[2] == Guess[2]:
    print("Y")
elif randomNumber[3] == Guess[3]:
    print("Y")
elif randomNumber[0] != Guess[0]:
    print("N")
elif randomNumber[1] != Guess[1]:
    print("N")
elif randomNumber[2] != Guess[2]:
    print("N")
elif randomNumber[3] != Guess[3]:
    print("N")
```

Comment: What is the user inputting? Changing the line to `Guess += list(input("Guess Number: "))` could fix it, but it depends on the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need four guesses to match for random numbers, you can also shorted your code using a list comp:

```
from random import randint

guessesTaken = 0
randomNumber = []

Guess = []
for x in range(4):
        tempNumber = str(randint(1, 9)) # compare string to string 
        randomNumber.append(tempNumber)
        Guess.append(input("Guess Number: "))

print("".join(["Y" if a==b else "N" for a,b in zip(Guess,randomNumber)]))
```

You can also use enumerate to check elements at matching indexes:

```
print("".join(["Y" if randomNumber[ind]==ele else "N"  for ind, ele in enumerate(Guess)]))
```

To give the user guesses in a loop:

```
from random import randint

guessesTaken = 0
randomNumber = [str(randint(1, 9))  for _ in range(4)] # create list of random nums

while guessesTaken < 10: 
    guesses = list(raw_input("Guess Number: ")) # create list of four digits
    check = "".join(["Y" if a==b else "N" for a,b in zip(guesses,randomNumber)])
    if check == "YYYY": # if check has four Y's we have a correct guess
        print("Congratulations, you are correct")
        break
    else:
        guessesTaken += 1 # else increment guess count and ask again
        print(check)
```

Comment: @AaronHall, I could not disagree more, how is it unreadable? it is a whole lot better than multiple needless if else statements

Comment: I agree with @PadraicCunningham, the list comprehension is much more readable. It's pretty trivial, anyone who understands basic python should really be able to read and understand that code

Comment: @user2981639, yes I agree, it literally almost reads as perfect english

Comment: Hi that is working really well but my explaining must not have been clear, i need the user to input the guess (which is obviously 4 numbers) then the output straight after the guess will display 'YYYY' or 'YYNNY' (again you get the point) and then the user keeps guessing until the output is 'YYYY' (But the user should only be able to guess up to 10 times) Thank you for your help

Comment: @paxyshack, have a look at the edit and see if we are on the same page

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hmmm. No because that still only feedbacks after 4 goes. what i need is: input= 2857 (just a random number guess)   then straight below that it should print: YYNY (depending on which ints match that of the random number generated) and the user should be able to keep guessing until their 10 goes are up (obviously they will know which number from the random generated number they have got right because there will be a 'Y' in its place, like process of elimination) sorry for confusion! thanks

Comment: so the user inputs for digits in one go? I have edited the code

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're only asking the user for one guess, and appending the guess to the `Guess` list. So the `Guess` list has one element, but you're using `Guess[1]`, `Guess[2]`, etc., which of course results in the `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

I'll rearrange your code a bit, so it doesn't stray too far from what you've done.

```
from random import randint

guessesTaken = 0
randomNumbers = []
Guess = [] # Combine your guesses with your loop

for x in range(4):
    tempNumber = randint(1, 9)
    randomNumbers.append(tempNumber)
    # This should be done four times too
    # In Python 2, instead of this:
    # Guess.append(input("Guess Number: ")) 
    # do this:
    Guess.append(int(raw_input("Guess Number: "))) #  raw_input and pass to int 
    # in python 3, raw_input becomes input, so do this instead:
    # Guess.append(int(input("Guess Number: "))) 


print(randomNumbers)
print(Guess)
```

You can combine these in a loop to avoid the repetitive code:

```
if randomNumbers[0] == Guess[0]:
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
if randomNumbers[1] == Guess[1]:
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
if randomNumbers[2] == Guess[2]:
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
if randomNumbers[3] == Guess[3]:
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
```

Perhaps, to print your desired result e.g. YNNY, like this:

```
result = []
for index in range(4):
    if randomNumbers[index] == Guess[index]:
        result.append("Y")
    else:
        result.append("N")
print(''.join(result))
```

If you want terser code use Python's ternary operation:

```
result = []
for index in range(4):
    result.append("Y" if randomNumbers[index] == Guess[index] else "N")
print(''.join(result))
```

Or use the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0` as indexes:

```
result = []
for index in range(4):
    result.append("NY"[randomNumbers[index] == Guess[index]])
print(''.join(result))
```

Comment: last time I checked strings and integers could not be equal

Comment: If it's python 2, integers put into input become ints.

Comment: an educated guess considering the OP is using parens for printing would lead me to believe they are using python 3 and if not they should be discouraged  using input