# Python Multiple number guessing game with varied feedback

Tags: python, numbers

Edit: I have been adjusting the 'check' to try and get it to work but i keep getting loads of errors..

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service - what have you tried, and what is the problem with it? Clearly, you will need to adapt the line `check = "".join(...)` to reflect whether `a > b` etc.

Comment: Hi there yes i understand that, I am new to python and have been changing the check to try and output what i need but i ended up causing all sorts of errors. thanks for the help

Comment: So where is the failing code, and what exactly are the errors? Provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and full traceback.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't see a problem here. OP clearly understands ternary operators, but is a bit lost when it comes to more than one test; evident from the question and code that they have posted.

Comment: @AlexThornton guess again: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26557773/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you just needed to rearrange your ternary statement with a couple more branches:

```
>>> randomNumber = ['3', '9', '3', '7']
>>> guess = ['2', '9', '4', '8']
>>> check = ''.join(b if a==b else 'H' if int(a)<int(b) else 'L' for a, b in zip(guess, randomNumber))
>>> print(check)
H9LL
```

Comment: (I've updated the code)Hi yes thats the problem i am getting it outputs this error to me TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: @paxyshack You forgot to do `int(b)`, which you must do because you need them both to be integers in order to compare their value.

Comment: Perfect but I need to display the number instead of 'Y' and i cant get my head around it

Comment: I just edited it. You simply needed to allow the variable to be put into the list. It should now display the number (`b`) instead of `'Y'`. And if it works, please consider accepting it with the tick. :)